# Laravel 5.0 Blade including tag causes slow render time and kills the page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm getting a weird issue with including tag. It slows down the page and sometimes kills it. I noted the render time with including tag and without it. See it in the screen shot:

http://prntscr.com/ho1cms http://prntscr.com/ho1boe

It has been working fine for a year, but now suddenly killing pages.

http://prntscr.com/ho1ebb

Comment: What's the permissions on that file you're trying to include?

Comment: maybe there is cache.. try to run php artisan cache:clear

Comment: cache no effect. @WhyAyala permission are default i have setup this script on two separate severs and on windows in my local storage with 775

Comment: well does your webserver have access to it with those permissions? is it the owner or in the group?

Comment: @WhyAyala its not permission error i guess, if you leave dead page check slow rending time.

Comment: Right, sorry @ShahidChaudhary Can you post some of the logic from this script because according to your photos you uploaded it's performing ~200 queries on the worst case.

Comment: Is 'snippets.__php_to_javascript_vars' really a blade.php? Maybe an error within the error page itself, can you provoke an error by hand (like include a view that is not existing)?

Comment: snippets.__php_to_javascript_vars exist. strange thing it dont show any error in log or in apache log just kill the page.

Comment: It is running 284 queries, and you are asking why it is slow?  Also, this isn't imgur, please don't post screenshots.  Just describe the problem, and show the code.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I belive you did not look at the problem 284 queries took 629.97 micro scnds  this is fine i have problem with view rendering

Comment: I guess you just found why you are getting such a poor response here on SO (no responses or comments in 2 months!?) - posting unclear screenshots which don't describe the problem, and no code.  You'll get a better response if you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and edit your question to suit.

Comment: Post the code of `snippets.__php_to_javascript_vars`. As code - not as an image!

Comment: @Konafets snippets.__php_to_javascript_vars is have blade  comments and same results with empty file.

Comment: Do you have a view composer that triggers on that included view?

Answer (score 0):

Since this include tag is mentioning javascript, it is possible that the slow down occurs in javascript context. Could be an asset failing to load in sync or just some very poor code running in sync. That would explain the blank page during loading.
Have you tried to look at how things where going in a browser console or even better browser network audit tool ?

Another thing could be some problems in the included files themselves, but I don't think you will find a reason in the include process itself.